# Sharepoint Powershell to list folder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I would like to list the folders of a Document library in sharepoint at a given level.

In MSDOS or linux this would be as simple as ls or dir.

So far to try to acheive this in powershell is some scripts that are quite long like here : https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-folder-in-document-library.html

Isn't there a simple was to list (not recursively) folders?

Answer (score 0):

Using PnP Powershell would be a "simple" way. In this case, you can just use `Get-PnPFolder` to retrieves folders residing inside a document library.

Reference: [Get-PnPFolder](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFolder.html).